# AL poner el resultado de una operación correctamente me da como si fuese incorrecto en python

Tags: python, random

no entiendo que puede ser el fallo pero al poner el resultado me dice mal

```
import random
numero1 = random.randint(1, 10)
numero2 = random.randint(1, 10)
resultado = numero1 * numero2
entrada = input('cuanto es {} * {}  '.format(numero1, numero2))
if resultado == entrada:
    print('bien')
else:
    print('mal')
```

Comment: Estas comparando un entero con un strig, tienes que transformar el input a un entero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas comparando una string con un int, por esto te dice que son diferentes.

Osea estas comparando por ejemplo "9" == 9.

Tendrías que convertir el input en int de la siguiente forma:

```
if int(operacion) == numero1*numero2:
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explicación

El comando input de Python devuelve lo escrito por el usuario en forma de cadena. Y la multiplicación de los dos números devuelve un numero. Eso significa que nunca serán iguales.

Para que entiendas mejor, te daré un ejemplo:

```
resultado = input("cuanto es 2x2?")
print(resultado == 4)
```

Incluso si el usuario ingresa 4, el print mandará False en consola. Por que?
Por que la cadena "4" no es lo mismo que el número 4. Estás haciendo la comparación "4" == 4

#### Solución

Si asumes que el usuario siempre escribirá un numero, puedes convertir lo ingresado por el usuario en un entero así:

```
resultado = int(input("cuanto es 2x2?"))
print(resultado == 4)
```

En este caso si el usuario ingresa 4 si dará verdadero.

*Advertencia*: Si el usuario ingresa algo que NO es un número, como "hola mundo", ocurrirá un error en el programa. Si no quieres que esto pase, revisa que la cadena se pueda convertir en número antes de hacer la conversión. Recomiendo [str.isdecimal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-isdecimal/#:%7E:text=isdecimal()%2DIt%20is%20a,decimal%20then%20it%20returns%20false.), que revisa que una cadena contenga unicamente numeros.